# Gulp cachebust not working

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have an issue related to cache clearing. 
My code is below:

**App.js**

```
require('angular')
require('angular-ui-router')
var MainController = require('./controllers/MainController')

angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home'
            template: '<h1>Hello world !</h1>'

        })

}])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MainController']);
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var CacheBuster = require('gulp-cachebust');

var cachebust = new CacheBuster();



gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: 'public',
        port: 4000 
    })
})

gulp.task('browserify', function(){

    return browserify('./app/app.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    //save it to public/js/ directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))
})
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return sass('sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
})
//Cache buster
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
    return gulp.src('styles/*.css')
        // Awesome css stuff 
        .pipe(cachebust.resources())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('build-html', ['build-css'], function () {
    return gulp.src('/*.html')
        // Awesome html stuff 
        .pipe(cachebust.references())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
gulp.task('build-js', ['build-css', 'build-html'], function () {
    return gulp.src('/*.js')
        // Awesome html stuff 
        .pipe(cachebust.resources())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', ['browserify', 'build-js'])
    gulp.watch('sass/style.scss', ['sass', 'build-css'])
    gulp.watch('index.html', [ 'build-html'])
})

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch'])
```

Basically I am seeing old html, js files. Haven't checked for other extensions. But probably this is not a right implementation.

I have used npm module from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cachebust).

Please help in setting it correctly.

Also, help me in knowing that how can I debug and check which tasks of gulp run? `Console.log` statements don't bother to spit out anything as far as my snippet is concerned.

UPDATE: 
**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>    
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UDDATE 2**

Here's the git repo

https://github.com/kushalmahajan/angular_boilerplate2.git

Comment: The code example was just dramatically changed so I removed my comment.

Comment: If you open your HTML file after the build-html task do the file references agree with the generated filenames? Also, if you inspect the source when loaded in the browser does the HTML look the same as in your file system?

Comment: Not exactly. The html doesn't reflects this `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: Same is with main.js file. It shows my config block commented which I remember doing at some stage.

Comment: I'm asking about your index.html or main.html or whatever name you've given it. The file that references your other resources such as compiled CSS and javascript.

Comment: I told you about both index.html (main file) and other js references as well I have my <div ui-view></div> inside the same.

Comment: If the entire content of you index.html file is `<div ui-view></div>` then you haven't yet reached a point where caching is a problem as you are not at all fetching your CSS or JS resources to the browser. Read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: I wish if I could  have done that mistake, my answer was right infront of me

Comment: Everything you've said so far points to that being your problem. You should add the entire content of your index.html to your question. Before and after the build-html gulp task.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now you need to also say how the "built" index.html file looks like. It should be in the public folder according to the build-html task.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know the filesnames of the resource files under public/

Comment: I added the git repo

Comment: I was editing the wrong index.html.  However, main.js file is still old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed like a gulp-cachebust problem only. I solved it by using `gulp-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem, you are seing old files so the

> cachebust.resources() / cachebust.references()

is not working, right? If it is the problem, I don't know the correct answer 100% sure but looking to the documentation seems you first have to change the MD5 and then rewrite the references. (It said *Rewrites references to resources which have been **renamed** according to their MD5 checksum.*) So I supose you have to first rename (*CacheBuster.resources()*) and then rewrite (*CacheBuster.references()*) But it's just a theory (and maybe you are already calling it in the right order).

However if you want to debug your gulp code (as you asked) and you have visual studio code you can add this code to your [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) file

```
    {
        //Name of configuration.
        "name": "debug gulp",
        "type": "node",
        //Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program":"${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
        //Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args":["server"],
        //Workspace path to the runtime to be debugged.
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        //Enviroment variables passed to the program.
        "env":{}, 
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
```

and call "debug gulp" in your launch options. You can put breakpoint everywhere in your gulp javascript (.js) code.

Comment: You got the problem right. But for debugging alone installing visual studio is too much

Comment: Well I found [this](http://www.greg5green.com/blog/debugging-gulp-js-tasks/) this searching in web. You can debug in browser and you just need a npm module installed globally. Gregory Green explain it very well. Sorry but I always use visual studio code method :P So I answered what I know.